# Writing regex to process sets of time from outside source

Tags: php, regex

I am writing a script that is taking in data from the outside world, where I am looking at when events happen, for example two sets of timings are:

```
Mon - Fri: 12:00 - 14:00, 18:00 - 22:30, Sat: 18:00 - 22:00
Tue, Wed, Thu: 17:30 - 23:00, Sat: 12:00 - 17:00, Sun: 17:00 - 22:30
```

As you can see, in each case the data is shown in a different way (mon-fri or tues,wed,thu). Can anyone give me some pointers on writing a form of regex / processing to take the data into an array such as:

```
$timing['mon'][1]['start'] = '12:00';
$timing['mon'][1]['finish'] = '14:00';
$timing['mon'][2]['start'] = '18:00';
$timing['mon'][2]['finish'] = '22:30';
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Do you have any control over how the data is brought in from the outside world? or are you scraping or something?

Comment: Unfortunately not.. the data is coming on a feed from another company (ie. completely legit) but the data is fixed in the way its presented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought I'd give it a go for fun.

I've assumed the two different lines are two different inputs. And have not really bothered with error checking. So if the format differs much from the sample you have provided this will most likely fail.

```
<?php
/**
 * Gets the days of the week in a range. e.g. given Mon Wed, will return an
 * array of Mon, Tue, Wed
 * @param string $start 3 letter day of the week (ucfirst)
 * @param string $end 3 letter day of the week (ucfirst)
 * @return array The days from $start to $end 
 */
function get_day_range($start, $end) {
    if ($start == $end)
        return array($start);

    $date = new DateTime($start);
    $days = array($start);
    while($date->format('D') != $end){
        $date->modify('+1 day');
        $days[] = $date->format('D');
    }

    return $days;
}

/**
 * Checks if the needle exists in the haystack
 * @param string $needle
 * @param string $haystack
 * @return bool 
 */
function instr($needle, $haystack) {
    return strpos($haystack, $needle) !== false;
}

function get_event_times($input) {
    preg_match_all('/
        (?<days>(
            (Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun)
            \s*[-,]?\s*
        )+):\s
        (?<times>
            (
                (
                    \d\d:\d\d
                        \s-\s
                    \d\d:\d\d
                ),?\s*
            )+
        )/x', $input, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    $return = array();

    foreach($matches as $match) {
        $days = $match['days'];

        // Is a day range
        if (instr(' - ', $days)) {
            list($start, $end) = explode(' - ', $days, 2);
            $days = get_day_range($start, $end);
        }

        // Is a list of days
        elseif (instr(', ', $days)) {
            $days = explode(', ', $days);
        }

        // Is just one day
        else {
            $days = array($days);
        }

        $times = trim($match['times'], ', ');
        $times = explode(', ', $times);

        foreach($days as $day) {
            foreach($times as $time) {
                list($start, $end) = explode(' - ', $time);
                $return[$day][] = array(
                    'start' => $start,
                    'end' => $end
                );
            }
        }
    }
    return $return;
}

$inputs = array(
    'Mon - Fri: 12:00 - 14:00, 18:00 - 22:30, Sat: 18:00 - 22:00',
    'Tue, Wed, Thu: 17:30 - 23:00, Sat: 12:00 - 17:00, Sun: 17:00 - 22:30'
);

foreach($inputs as $input) {
    var_dump(get_event_times($input));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$string = "Mon - Fri: 12:00 - 14:00, 18:00 - 22:30, Sat: 18:00 - 22:00
Tue, Wed, Thu: 17:30 - 23:00, Sat: 12:00 - 17:00, Sun: 17:00 - 22:30";

preg_match_all("/([a-zA-Z\-\s\,]+): ([0-9\:\,\s\-]+)/", $string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

$data = array();

foreach ($matches[1] as $key => $day){

    //Split the data and remove whitespace.
    $values = explode(",", $matches[2][$key][0]);
    foreach ($values as $a => $b) $values[$a] = trim($b); if (empty($values[$a])) unset($values[$a]);

    //Loop each set and split the stand and end.
    foreach ($values as $a => $b){

        $splits = explode("-", $b);
        $values[$a] = array("Start" => $splits[0], "End" => $splits[1]);

    } //end foreach

    //Place the new data in the array.
    $data[trim($day[0])] = $values;

} //end foreach

echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);

?>
```

The above code will allow for change within your data, as you will note, the keys from the array will remain as "Mon - Fri" as per your data, which as there is no standard in the formatting of it, appears it is subject to change anyways.

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks for that - I noticed that it doesnt pick up the tues,wed,thu: section - only seems to get the Thu: part. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's fixed, if you look at the regular expression, I've added the comma, which now works for you. :)

Comment: Hi Richard, I want to thank you for your reply which although works, the solution by Jacob fits my purpose more / puts everything into a single array per day of the week. I've marked you up as useful though.

Comment: Thank you very much, although it may not be the code used, I'm glad I helped and also happy at the amount of response you got, hope your application does well. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need more than just a regex to solve that problem.  I'd start by breaking it up into smaller chunks.  Since delimiters are serving double (or triple) duty in that format, you can't just break it up along delimiters, so you'll need to process it in chunks.  First, I'd break everything before and after the first colon apart.  The first part is your day specifier, so parse that - if it's the comma separated list, just split it into a list of keys.  If it's the range, use a loop to build out the list of keys.  After that, you have a list of times.  I'd loop something like `\d\d:\d\d - \d\d:\d\d,?` until it failed to match (indicating either end of line or another entry), applying each interval to the key set you generated earlier, with an incremental count for your second index there.  Once that pattern fails to match, start the whole process over again:

1. Split off up to the first colon to get the day specifier
2. Process the day specifier as either a list or a range (matching on the dash maybe to tell which case you have) into a list of days
3. Take up to the next comma or the end of the string (or use the time range pattern) to get the time range
4. Apply that time range to the list of days from step 2
5. If there is another time pattern, loop back to 3, otherwise loop back to 1